# ODATA query formation

Tags: json, odata

**I need to form the odata query for the below scenario, kindly help me on this:**
Eg:
In a `TABLE EMPLOYEE`, We have duplicated records based on the `EMP NAME`. `LastUpdated time` Column is one more column in the table. Now i need to retrieve all the Unique rows(based on `EMP NAME`) with the condition having, for the particular employee the `LastUpdated Time` Column should be `max/latest` one.

Comment: What have you tried? As far as I can assume you query must look somehting like this `http://myendpoint.com/EMPLOYEE?$filter=LastUpdated eq null&$orderby=LastUpdated desc`. If you are searching for a grouped result: It is not supported by odata, you have to use javascript or linq to group the result.

Comment: The client Table is having the duplicate records and we need to fetch only the distinct records using ODATA query.
For Eg: “Countries” table is having duplicate records as shown below,
{
"ID":5301,"CountryCode":"AD",,"LastUpdateDate":"2014-07-05T09:21:07-04:00"
},{
"ID":5303,"CountryCode":"AD","LastUpdateDate":"2014-06-05T09:21:07-04:00"
}
 In this Eg: “CountryCode” = AD is duplicated  and we need to fetch only one record for that code by filtering the  MAX “LastUpdateDate” column. So only the row should be retrieved having the latest updated date in the “LastUpdateDate” Column

Comment: As I said. As far as I know, grouping is not supported in odata.